# Vue.js manage cookie send by Back End

Tags: node.js, vue.js, cookies, vuejs3

I implemented an end point in my Back End to login users, which sends back a jwt token and a cookie that contains this same token. The functions executed when calling this endpoint are the following:

```
exports.login = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  // 1) Check if email and password exist
  if (!email || !password) {
    return next(new AppError('Please provide email and password', 400));
  }

  // 2) Check if user exists && password is correct
  const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select('+password');

  if (!user || !(await user.correctPassword(password, user.password))) {
    return next(new AppError('Incorrect email or password', 401));
  }

  // 3) If everything ok, send token to client
  createSendToken(user, 200, res);
});

const createSendToken = (user, statusCode, res) => {
  const token = signToken(user._id);
  const cookieOptions = {
    expires: new Date(
      Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES_IN * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    ),
    httpOnly: true,
  };

  res.cookie('jwt', token, cookieOptions);

  // Remove password from output
  user.password = undefined;

  res.status(statusCode).json({
    status: 'success',
    token,
    data: {
      user,
    },
  });
};

const signToken = (id) => {
  return jwt.sign({ id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN,
  });
};
```

When calling this endpoint from Postman I get no error, I receive all information I should get and I also receive the cookie. The problem I have is that when calling this from my Front End, a Vue.js application, I get the data but the cookie doesn't get saved in the browser. This is the method I created to test this:

```
async testLogin() {
      const data = {
        email: 'test@test.com',
        password: 'pass1234',
      };
      const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        credentials: 'include',
      };

      const response = await fetch(
        'http://127.0.0.1:3000/v1/users/login',
        requestOptions
      );
      const responseData = await response.json();
      console.log(responseData);
      const cookie = response.token;
      document.cookie = cookie;
    },
```

Once this gets executed I receive the json object from Back End containing the status, data and token, but there's no cookie saved into my browser. I need this later to see which role has the logged in user and grant or deny access to certain pages, and as far as I know, I need to send to Back End this jwt token to check it. How can I save this cookie on the browser?

I already checked the CORS Policy and my Back End it's accepting requests from my Front End without problems, I had to add this:

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:8080',
  credentials: true, // Allow credentials (cookies)
};

router.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Comment: Backend is returning cookie with `httpOnly: true` so js won't be able to access this cookie.

Comment: As @DinhTX says, you cannot access the cookie with the httpOnly flag with JS. But you should see the cookie in Chrome dev tools under the Application tab. Do you see it there?

Comment: @Gabe I'm pretty new at working with cookies, this is the Cookies side on the Application tab on Chrome dev tools https://imgur.com/a/8aHT49w . I also tried to print the cookie after line `const cookie = response.token` and I get an `undefined` that matches with the value of the cookie of the Application tab. Should this work without the `HttpOnly` option? This is a local project and will never get into a server or something similar so I guess I don't need that option to be active.

Comment: You are doing something odd on the client side, trying to set `document.cookie`. Besides the format that is wrong, it should be a key=value string [1], the JWT cookie is already set by the server and the browser will store it, so there is no need to set it on the client. The client wil automatically sent the cookie back to the server on the next requests. 
  [1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#write_a_new_cookie

Comment: @Gabe If I didn't get it wrong, you mean that there's no need to manage anything in the client side, the browser should automatically store that cookie and send it with any other request made to the server right? I can also use localStorage to save the jwt token (it is also send in the response), but I would rather get it working with the cookie

Comment: Yes, that’s correct. No need to use localStorage. On the server you need to get the cookie from the request and verify the token. Here’s a basic example with node and express: https://dev.to/franciscomendes10866/using-cookies-with-jwt-in-node-js-8fn

Comment: @Gabe Followed the example and ended up with the same problem. The cookie is received when using Postman to test the API but when calling it from the Vue.js app there is no cookie :/

Comment: What if you use an Incognito tab?

Comment: @Gabi, neither, I also tried in 4 other browser that I don't use